# Storing cookielib cookies in a database

Tags: python, urllib2, cookielib

I'm using the `cookielib` module to handle HTTP cookies when using the `urllib2` module in Python 2.6 in a way similar to this snippet:

```
import cookielib, urllib2
cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
r = opener.open("http://example.com/")
```

I'd like to store the cookies in a database. I don't know whats better - serialize the `CookieJar` object and store it or extract the cookies from the `CookieJar` and store that. I don't know which one's better or how to implement either of them. I should be also be able to recreate the `CookieJar` object.

Could someone help me out with the above?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`cookielib.Cookie`, to quote its docstring (in its [sources](http://svn.python.org/view/python/trunk/Lib/cookielib.py?revision=81466&view=markup)),

> is deliberately a very simple class. 
>   It just holds attributes.

so `pickle` (or other serialization approaches) are just fine for saving and restoring each `Cookie` instance.

As for `CookieJar`, `set_cookie` sets/adds one cookie instance, `__iter__` (to use the latter, just do a `for` loop on the jar instance) returns all cookie instances it holds, one after the other.

A subclass that you can use to see how to make a "cookie jar on a database" is [BSDDBCookieJar](http://codespeak.net/svn/wwwsearch/mechanize/trunk/attic/BSDDBCookieJar.py) (part of `mechanize`, but I just pointed specifically to the jar source code file) -- it doesn't load all cookies in memory, but rather keeps them in a `self._db` which is a bsddb instance (mostly-on-disk, dict-lookalike hash table constrained to having only strings as keys and values) and uses pickle for serialization.

If you *are* OK with keeping every cookie in memory during operations, simply `pickle`ing the jar is simplest (and, of course, put the blob in the DB and get it back from there when you're restarting) -- `s = cPickle.dumps(myJar, -1)` gives you a big byte string for the whole jar (and policy thereof, of course, not just the cookies), and `theJar = cPickle.loads(s)` rebuilds it once you've reloaded `s` as a blob from the DB.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a very simple class that I have implemented that can load/dump cookies from/to a string based on Alex' suggestion of using `pickle`.

```
from cookielib import CookieJar
try:
    import cPickle as pickle
except ImportError:
    import pickle

class StringCookieJar(CookieJar):
    def __init__(self, string=None, policy=None):
        CookieJar.__init__(self, policy)
        if string:
            self._cookies = pickle.loads(string)

    def dump(self):
        return pickle.dumps(self._cookies)
```